# Javascript - Impedir selecionar option do select menor que outro

Tags: javascript, html-select, matemática

Olá.

Estou fazendo um sistema para agendamento por horário. Tenho 2 select's: início e fim.

Preciso de uma função para impedir que o horário de fim, não possa ser menor que o de inicio + 3. Ex: inicio = 10, o fim deverá ser no mínimo 13, e não deixar selecionar 12 ou menor.

Abaixo o que tenho já:

```
<div>
<select id="inicio" onchange="horainicio()">
<option value="9">9:00</option>
<option value="10">10:00</option>
<option value="11">11:00</option>
<option value="12">12:00</option>
<option value="13">13:00</option>
<option value="14">14:00</option>
<select>

<select id="fim" onchange="horafim()">
<option value="12">12:00</option>
<option value="13">13:00</option>
<option value="14">14:00</option>
<option value="15">15:00</option>
<option value="16">16:00</option>
<option value="17">17:00</option>
<select>
Resultado:<br/>
<input type="text" id="resultado">
<button type="button" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</div>
<script>

function horainicio() {
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
document.getElementById("fim").value = parseInt(inicio) + 3;
resultado.value = document.getElementById("fim").value-document.getElementById("inicio").value;
}

function horafim(){
resultado.value = document.getElementById("fim").value-document.getElementById("inicio").value;
}
</script>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: O que deve acontecer? O outro select ser mudado automáticamente ou ficar em branco? Irá haver somente intervalos de hora completa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o amigo @Sergio comentou, se expor as condições, dizer o que deve acontecer, a resposta pode ser mais precisa, mas essa validação pode ser feita de uma maneira bem simples, se o valor da hora inicial + 3 for maior que o valor da hora final selecionada, faz o que tu quiser (bloqueia, etc.)

```
var horaIni = parseInt(document.getElementById("inicio").value);
var horaFim = parseInt(document.getElementById("fim").value);
if(horaIni + 3 > horaFim){
  //...
}
```

Segue um snippet com um exemplo (caso não for uma hora válida, deixo o select em branco):

```js
function horafim(value) {
  var horaIni = parseInt(document.getElementById("inicio").value);
  var horaFim = parseInt(value);
  if (horaIni + 3 > horaFim) {
    alert("Hora inválida.");
    document.getElementById("fim").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="inicio">
<option value="9">9:00</option>
<option value="10">10:00</option>
<option value="11">11:00</option>
<option value="12">12:00</option>
<option value="13">13:00</option>
<option value="14">14:00</option>
<select>

<select id="fim" onchange="horafim(value)">
<option value="12">12:00</option>
<option value="13">13:00</option>
<option value="14">14:00</option>
<option value="15">15:00</option>
<option value="16">16:00</option>
<option value="17">17:00</option>
<select>
</div>
```

Comment: O que tem que acontecer (não sei se é possivel) impedir que escolha um valor do fim menor que o de inicio + 3. Como seu ocultasse os options menores.

Por exemplo, se inicio for 10, as opções do fim começam em 13, se inicio for 12 as opções do fim começam em 15.

Comment: @LeandroTeraoka isso já está fazendo então, correto? Da uma olhada no snippet.

Comment: É isso memos, obrigado (tão simples), só alterei para ao invés de mudar para valor em branco, alterar para valor do inicio +3